# Add a non-breaking space button to the toolbar in CKeditor

Tags: javascript, symfony, ckeditor

I'm facing a problem with CKeditor (V4.17.0). I'm using it in a Symfony (V5) project. I installed the WYSIWYG with this [doc](https://symfony.com/bundles/FOSCKEditorBundle/current/usage/ckeditor.html). Then I downloaded the [Non-breaking space](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/nbsp) plugin, I placed it in the path `public/bundles/fosckeditor/plugins` and I configured my yaml file:

```yaml
twig:
    form_themes:
        - '@FOSCKEditor/Form/ckeditor_widget.html.twig'

fos_ck_editor:
    default_config: config
    configs:
        config:
            allowedContent: true
            extraPlugins: 'nbsp'
            removePlugins: 'elementspath,exportpdf,image,media, about'
            toolbar:
                - { name: "styles", items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Strike' ] }
                - { name: "plugins", items: ['insertNbsp'] }
                - { name: "paragraph", items: ['NumberedList'] }
        plugins:
            nbsp:
                path: 'ckeditor/plugins/nbsp/'
                filename: 'plugin.js'
```

My webpack.config.js :

```js
.copyFiles([
        {
            from: './assets/images',
            to: 'images/[path][name].[ext]',
        },
        {
            from: './node_modules/ckeditor4/',
            to: 'ckeditor/[path][name].[ext]',
            pattern: /\.(js|css)$/,
            includeSubdirectories: false,
        },
        {
            from: './node_modules/ckeditor4/adapters',
            to: 'ckeditor/adapters/[path][name].[ext]'
        },
        {
            from: './node_modules/ckeditor4/lang',
            to: 'ckeditor/lang/[path][name].[ext]'
        },
        {
            from: './node_modules/ckeditor4/skins',
            to: 'ckeditor/skins/[path][name].[ext]'
        },
        {
            from: './node_modules/ckeditor4/vendor',
            to: 'ckeditor/vendor/[path][name].[ext]'
        },
        {
            from: './public/bundles/fosckeditor/plugins',
            to: 'ckeditor/plugins/[path][name].[ext]'
        },
     ])
```

The editor appear on the page, in my toolbar I've got everything I asked except the Non-breaking space plugin.

[image]

How can I insert into it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this plugin is used that way. You can't, if I'm not mistaken, load that into the toolbar.

Would it be possible for you to use this source code instead of the original plugin.js

```js
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'nbsp',
{
    init : function( editor )
    {
    editor.ui.addButton('Insert &nbsp', {
        label: 'Insert &nbsp;',
        command: 'insertNbsp',
        toolbar: 'insert',
        icon: this.path + 'icons/icon.png'
    });
        // Insert &nbsp; if Ctrl+Space is pressed:
        editor.addCommand( 'insertNbsp', {
            exec: function( editor ) {
                editor.insertHtml( '&nbsp;', 'text' );
            }
        });
        editor.setKeystroke( CKEDITOR.CTRL + 32 /* space */, 'insertNbsp' );
    }

} );
```

think about creating an icons folder as well as an icon of your choice to see a button in your toolbar.